# Implementing Custom External Identity Button on Visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, single-sign-on

I'm currently trying to implement a button on my organizations customized visualforce page which I want to have the exact same functionality as the button in this screenshot (the googleLogin button, which uses SSO and a google external identity):

[image: google login]

Where would I find the information on how to implement this button? If I inspect element (or f12) on the button, it tells me it's a simple onclick link, not a visualforce method. Does this mean I can simply copy the link in the onclick and paste it into my button?

If any more information is needed / left out please tell me.

Thank you for any assistance.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?